# Ошибки из за постоянного коннекта к MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Столкнулся с проблемой большого кол-ва коннектов к MySql, и решил использовать персистент коннект, чтобы не плодить такое кол-во коннектов, проблема решилась, но стали часто вылетать ошибки такого рода. Прошу подсказать в какую сторону копать

```
[Wed Nov 14 02:25:52 2018] [error] [client 10.160.9.12] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in /SCRIPTS/FBII/EXTRA/API_IVR/_CORE/DBLayer.php on line 153
```

Comment: Что значит "Столкнулся с проблемой большого кол-ва коннектов"???
Ошибка означает таймаут соединения. Без основного кода и принципа работы вашего приложения более не помочь.
Процентов 146 вы не закрываете коннект и пытаетесь в него повторно долбиться.

Comment: Я до этого не использовал постоянное соединение Mysql, и выросло большое кол-во TCP коннектов высящих в таймауте, то есть было большое кол-во запросов и на каждый поднимался коннект к MySql,из за этого и висело все, решил перейти на персистент коннект, помогло, но стала появляться ошибка таймаута